# Time complexity of adding a vertex to adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

Multiple sources state that the time complexity of adding a vertex to an adjacency list is O(1) and my understanding right now is that this is because of optimizations with hash tables.

If we use an array of linked lists, then the time complexity is O(V) right? Because to add a new vertex we have to make a new array of size V + 1.

I just wanted to confirm my line of thinking against pre-existing information.

Comment: if the array is, say, resized double when necessary, the amortized time complexity is linear because this only happens so often.

Comment: I mean, it's constant - cheap.

Comment: @clwhisk Doesn't a similar line of thinking apply to an adjacency matrix, which is O(V^2)?